# Unable to set field width using binding expression

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a very simple requirement, which is to dynamically set the width of several (not all, just several) columns in my `XamDataGrid` to 0 if a binding expression is met.

The columns in question invariably follow this structure:

```
<igDP:UnboundField Name="Data Field 1" BindingPath="SrcEntity.Field1" 
    Width="{Binding Path=DataContext.GetDynamicWidth}">
    <igDP:Field.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings AllowHiding="Always" AllowResize="True" />
    </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>
```

When I debug the application, the `DataContext.GetDynamicWidth` is getting called as expected, and is returning the width value as expected (either `0` or `Double.NaN`). But on the grid, the actual width is unchanged for these columns that have the dynamic binding to their width.

Can anyone tell me if this is an Infragistics bug, or if I'm missing something here?

Note: I've also tried the following field settings:

```
<igDP:FieldSettings AllowHiding="Always" 
    AllowResize="True" CellWidth="{Binding Path=DataContext.GetDynamicWidth}" />
```

This was also unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

The Field isn't part of the visual or logical tree so binding to the DataContext isn't possible.  To work around this you can bind to a StaticResource instead.